# Collaborative Text Editor project using tinyMCE and Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tinymce, gettext, settext

I am trying to build a collaborative text editor using (1) tinyMCE as editor and (2) Node js + Socket.io for messaging between peers.

The second part (2) is no problem, messages are coming and going, without any problem. But I can't find the right method to get the typed characters and append these to the other peer's editor window.

Right now I use: **tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()** to get the text and **tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(target_textarea)** to set it on the other side. The problem is that the second method replaces everything in the peer's editor deleting in the same time what was written already.

I have tried concat() as well using a second variable, but this won't work either.

Maybe someone has a tip on how to achieve this collaborative editor.

Thanks!

code:

```
...

var text = '';
    socket.on('textarea_changed', function(textarea_content){
        console.log(textarea_content);
        //text = text + ' ' + (textarea_content);
        //console.log(text);
        $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(textarea_content));
    });


  //if any key is pressed
  function tinyMceKeydown(){  
        //send message
        console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
        socket.emit('keypressed', 'tom');
    };


...
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used tinyMce and haven't had a look at the API. 
However one suggestion that i can offer, which i believe might help, is that you might want to change your approach.

Rather than transmitting and replacing the entire text , you might want to:
- Identify the new text typed/inserted 
- Send this to the second user (Socket.io)
- In the editor of the second user, insert this new text (using the relevant API, i.e. insert at the same position using some text range api)

One of the other benefits (apart from losing changes that the other user made), is you only send incremental updates (only the changes), as opposed to sending the entire text.